# Optimise PDO function when Inserting Data within a PHP loop

Tags: php, mysql

I need the advice of an advanced (or at least more advanced than myself) SQL/PDO engineer.

I have an associative array which is 7 keys in length. Within each child array contains 5 elements, one of these is an array containing 3 elements.

Currently I loop through this array with an inner loop also, updating the database. It works faultlessly. The only issue I have is the speed. It currently takes around 15-20 seconds to run. This is a problem because it runs 4 separate times on a single page resulting in a 60+ seconds to execute.

I am using PDO within bind parameters. Could anybody shed any light on how I could optimise further this query?

```
try {
    $dbh = $myDBConn;
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO myTable1 (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10)
        SELECT myTable2.ID, :color, :make, NULL, :model, :height, :width, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
        FROM myTable2
        WHERE myTable2.ID IN (SELECT myTable3.ID FROM myTable3
        WHERE myTable3.Col2 = :color
        AND Col4 = :Height AND Col5 = :Width)");

    foreach ($myArray as $key => $val) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':Height', $val1['height'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Width', $val1['width'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':make', $val1['make'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 6);
        $stmt->bindParam(':color', $val1['color'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        foreach($myArray['nested'] as $key2 => $val2){
            $stmt->bindParam(':height', $val2['height'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
            $stmt->bindParam(':width', $val2['width'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
            $stmt->bindParam(':model', $val2['model'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }

    $dbh = null;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print($e->getMessage);
}
```

Comment: Quick thought - if you're using INNODB engine, would wrapping the whole thing in a transaction and committing it once help any?

Comment: @markdwhite is it using `MyISAM` unfortunately.

Comment: SO is for questions reagarding programming errors. This seems more suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: @Peter - well, based on the given code you could check for better indices on myTable2 and myTable3, using combined indices if appropriate. Though (sorry) it has the odour of a code smell to me. Are you trying to fit this solution into a bad DB design?

Comment: Yes, I am in a position where a complete data re-structure is out of the question but they require something that their data is not naturally structured to deal with. Normally loops within a loop spells trouble.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

35 queries cannot be an issue. It should run in less than a second. Your problem is neither PDO or prepared statements related. It's your query that runs slow. Most likely your table  is using Innodb engine with `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` set to some value other than 2.

Thus, first of all check if it's indeed myisam. Than double-check it.
Then prepend run your insert query with `EXPLAIN` and run it in console to see the numbers.

ON the second glance it's definitely your query. You have to ask another question, without all this prepared stuff, but on the query only, providing example values and the result of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` query, followed by the `show warnings` command, to reveal a translated query.

I have a feeling that mysql is translating your subquery into join and to unoptimized one.

Comment: Thanks. It is definately myisam. I ran an SQL explain on the schema and table. As regards 35 queries, it's in fact 105 (7x5x3), and the ID's within the `IN()` condition is around 1000. This amount to 1000 inserts multiplied by 105. It's a pretty intense update in all fairness. What time scale would you say is acceptable for this kind of query? In an ideal world i'd like to get it below 10 seconds.

Comment: I have an sqlite(different i know) database that writes 30.000 records < 1 second with transaction, so 10 seconds without transaction sounds about right depending on complexity of queries and cpu time spent. without a transaction system there is small possiblity to inscreasing speed. Is there no way you can convert the table to a transaction supported one?